# R package builds & pkgbuild::compile_dll failing; New files in /tmp are not executable

Tags: r, permissions, devtools, tmp, rstan

I'm attempting to build a package and install R packages that use `Rccp`. These are failing because files in `/tmp` are not executable.

These problems arose after switching to a new Dell xps 13 pre-installed with Ubuntu 18.04. For the build, I've been using `pkgbuild::compile_dll` to compile some C code with `Rccp`. I only found out about the problem installing new packages while troubleshooting the problem with `compile_dll`. This confirmed that its not a problem with `pkgbuild`.

Here is the error message from `compile_dll`:

```
> pkgbuild::compile_dll()
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
  method         from 
  [.quosures     rlang
  c.quosures     rlang
  print.quosures rlang
Re-compiling spstan
─  installing *source* package ‘spstan’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R 
Installation and Administration Manual'
─  removing 
‘/home/connor/tmp/RtmpC0EMxX/devtools_install_570e38f2a7e3/spstan’
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), 
error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command error
```

There's plenty of help out there for this it seems, except that none of the solutions are working for me. Here is what I've tried.

1. Remount `/tmp` as in
   https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/32

Remount /tmp and enable executable files be entering the following in the terminal:

`sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp`

Which gives the following error message: `mount point not mounted or bad option.` Since `/tmp` isn't mounted separately on my computer, its part of the root filesystem, the above solution fails because `/tmp` can't be remounted.

2. Following the instructions from the R Installation and Administration Manual, make sure TMPDIR points to some temporary file system in which scripts are allowed to be executed. So I made a new tmp folder called `~/Rtmp` and mounted it:

   mkdir ~/Rtmp
    mount -t tmpfs -o exec ~/Rtmp

Also adding the following line to my `~/.Renviron` file:

```
TMPDIR=/home/connor/Rtmp
```

and adding the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs           /home/connor/Rtmp            tmpfs   exec   0       0
```

and then rebooting the computer before running `pkgbuild::compile_dll()` again. I get the same error message but I could confirm that R was using `/Rtmp` folder I directed it to.

3. Following some advice here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2421441 change permissions on the /tmp folder recursively with

`sudo chmod -R 777 ~/tmp`

This also fails. The problem seems to be that `compile_dll` is creating a new script that it wants to run and the permissions on the folder aren't the default for new files that get added to it.

When I print out the permissions for `/tmp`, the script that is failing with `compile_dll` is listed without the same permissions as all the older files:

```
drwx------  3 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 15:20 RtmpC0EMxX
drwxrwxrwx  9 root   root   4096 Jun 23 09:53 RtmpGb3QiA
drwxrwxrwx  3 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 10:44 RtmpI9hu1U
drwxrwxrwx  2 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 10:41 RtmpIgi5su
drwxrwxrwx  2 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 10:07 RtmpK4p4Od
drwxrwxrwx  4 root   root   4096 Jun 23 09:17 RtmppdbqeT
drwxrwxrwx 10 root   root   4096 Jun 23 09:54 RtmpR4Cc9c
drwxrwxrwx 14 root   root   4096 Jun 23 10:13 Rtmpuweyxz
drwxrwxrwx  2 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 10:07 RtmpwN9SbT
drwxrwxrwx  2 connor connor 4096 Jun 23 10:04 RtmpY7g0NK
```

So I'm still stuck. Am I doing something wrong here? Or do I need to start looking somewhere else for the source of the problem?